# 400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port only from ruy

Tags: ruby

I Want To send a request to my website URL and get a response but only in ruby I'm getting this output

```
<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using also other languages like python, javascript, PHP but only in ruby I get this issue

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

# insert your api key here
api = "my_api_key"

# replace my_email@my_email.com to email you want to validate 
email = 'my_email@my_email.com'

# api url
uri = URI.parse( "https://emailvalidator.pawnhost.com/dashboard/api/"+ api +"/" ); params = {'email'=> email}

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port) 
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path) 
request.set_form_data( params )


# instantiate a new Request object
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new( uri.path+ '?' + request.body ) 

response = http.request(request)
puts response.body
```

I want my API response but i get that

Comment: Did you get the solution for this?